# Google Colabで特定のサイトへhttpsリクエストを送信すると、UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING エラーが発生する

Tags: python, python3, google-colaboratory

Google Colab上から以下のサイトへPythonのrequestsパッケージを利用してhttpsリクエストを発行すると、`UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING` エラーが発生しました。

アクセスしようとしたサイト：
https://demo-kabuka.e-shiten.jp/e_api_v4r3/

エラーが発生したコードは以下です。

```
import requests

response = requests.get(url='https://demo-kabuka.e-shiten.jp/e_api_v4r3/')
display(response)
display(response.content)
```

以下はGoogle Colabでエラーが発生したときの実行結果です。

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLEOFError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, body, headers, retries, timeout, chunked, response_conn, preload_content, decode_content, enforce_content_length)
    466             try:
--> 467                 self._validate_conn(conn)
    468             except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

18 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
   1091         if conn.is_closed:
-> 1092             conn.connect()
   1093 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py in connect(self)
    641 
--> 642         sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
    643             sock=sock,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(sock, cert_reqs, ssl_version, ssl_minimum_version, ssl_maximum_version, cert_file, key_file, key_password, ca_certs, ca_cert_dir, ca_cert_data, assert_hostname, assert_fingerprint, server_hostname, ssl_context, tls_in_tls)
    782 
--> 783     ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
    784         sock=sock,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir, key_password, ca_cert_data, tls_in_tls)
    468 
--> 469     ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
    470     return ssl_sock

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, ssl_context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
    512 
--> 513     return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)

/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    512         # ctx._wrap_socket()
--> 513         return self.sslsocket_class._create(
    514             sock=sock,

/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py in _create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
   1070                         raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
-> 1071                     self.do_handshake()
   1072             except (OSError, ValueError):

/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py in do_handshake(self, block)
   1341                 self.settimeout(None)
-> 1342             self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1343         finally:

SSLEOFError: [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, preload_content, decode_content, **response_kw)
    789             # Make the request on the HTTPConnection object
--> 790             response = self._make_request(
    791                 conn,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, body, headers, retries, timeout, chunked, response_conn, preload_content, decode_content, enforce_content_length)
    490                 new_e = _wrap_proxy_error(new_e, conn.proxy.scheme)
--> 491             raise new_e
    492 

SSLError: [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    485         try:
--> 486             resp = conn.urlopen(
    487                 method=request.method,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, preload_content, decode_content, **response_kw)
    843 
--> 844             retries = retries.increment(
    845                 method, url, error=new_e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    514             reason = error or ResponseError(cause)
--> 515             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    516 

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='demo-kabuka.e-shiten.jp', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /e_api_v4r3/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-1f9596a04e09> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import requests
      2 
----> 3 response = requests.get(url='https://demo-kabuka.e-shiten.jp/e_api_v4r3/')
      4 display(response)
      5 display(response.content)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     71     """
     72 
---> 73     return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
     74 
     75 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     57     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     58     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 59         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     60 
     61 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    587         }
    588         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 589         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    590 
    591         return resp

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    701 
    702         # Send the request
--> 703         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    704 
    705         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    515             if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
    516                 # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
--> 517                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    518 
    519             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='demo-kabuka.e-shiten.jp', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /e_api_v4r3/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)')))
```

一方、Shellのcurlでhttpsリクエストを発行したところ、正しくレスポンスを取得できました。(レスポンスはshift-jisのため一部文字化けします。)

```
!curl https://demo-kabuka.e-shiten.jp/e_api_v4r3/
```

Google Colab以外のパソコンでは、Pythonのrequestsパッケージも正しく動作しているため、Google Colab固有の問題かと思うのですが、原因を調べる方法など教えていただけないでしょうか？

requestsパッケージのバージョンは 2.31.0 でした。

```
!pip3 show requests

Name: requests
Version: 2.31.0
Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.
Home-page: https://requests.readthedocs.io
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: me@kennethreitz.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
Requires: certifi, charset-normalizer, idna, urllib3
Required-by: CacheControl, chromadb, community, earthengine-api, embedchain, fastai, folium, gcsfs, gdown, google-api-core, google-cloud-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-colab, gspread, gTTS, jira, kaggle, langchain, langsmith, moviepy, music21, openai, pandas-datareader, panel, pooch, posthog, pymystem3, python-keycloak, requests-oauthlib, requests-toolbelt, spacy, Sphinx, tensorboard, tensorflow-datasets, torchdata, torchtext, torchvision, tweepy, twilio, yfinance, youtube-transcript-api
```

Comment: 該当のURLはブラウザで見ると`本ページは引っ越し致しました。`, `新しいＵＲＬはこちらです。`と出てきます。そのURLを使うと処理は正常に行われるようですので、特に理由が無ければ新しいURLを使ってみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: コメント、ありがとうございます。
実は、この引っ越し前のURLの、サブドメインに、Web-APIのエントリーポイントがあり、GoogleColabからもAPIを利用したく、質問いたしました。

Comment: 新しいURLの説明にはv4r4という新しい版数になっているのでAPIのエントリポイントも同様に引っ越して古いAPIは使えなくなったとか、あるいはもしかしたら古いAPI/エントリポイントでもエントリポイント指定だけでなくパラメータ等をきちんと指定すると応答が返るとか、あるのでは？ 新しいURLのほうにマニュアルやサンプルプログラムもあるようですので、確かめてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ありがとうございます。確認したところ、引っ越し前のサイトにv4r4用の新しいエントリポイントが追加されていました。こちらも旧バージョンと同様に、エラーが発生しました。(https://demo-kabuka.e-shiten.jp/e_api_v4r4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

エラーメッセージにはもう一つ関連するモジュール`urllib3`があり、そちらの版数が`新しい`ことが原因ですね。
以下のように 1.xx系の最終版を指定して置き換えると動作するようになりました。

```
!pip3 install -U urllib3==1.26.16
```

結果はこうなりました。

```
<Response [200]>
b'<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<!--\n Product:\n \tmfds (realtime stock price board application modules).\n \n Copyright:\n \tCopyright (C) 2000 GOODLOTS CO.,LTD. ALL RIGHT RESERVED.\n \n Revision:\n\t$Id: mfds_json_api_move.html 1062 2023-02-28 04:45:07Z yoshi $\n \n Function:\n \tMFDS, json-api HP menu module (v4.0-000).\n\n Create:\n\t2022.06.08\n\tY.Yoshizawa\n\n-->\n<html lang="ja">\n<head>\n\t<meta http-equiv="content-type"        content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS">\n\t<meta http-equiv="content-style-type"  content="text/css">\n\t<meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript">\n  \t<script\ttype="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>\n\t<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mfds_json_api_sample.css" />\n\t<title>\x97\xa7\x89\xd4\x8f\xd8\x8c\x94\x81E\x82\x85\x8ex\x93X\x81E\x82`\x82o\x82h</title>\n</head>\n<body style="display:none;">\n\t<!-- page title begin. -->\n\t<table>\n\t<tr>\n\t\t<td><a href="mfds_json_api_menu.html"><img class="page_logo" /></a></td>\n\t\t<td><span class="page_title">\x97\xa7\x89\xd4\x8f\xd8\x8c\x94\x81E\x82\x85\x8ex\x93X\x81E\x82`\x82o\x82h\x90\xea\x97p\x83y\x81[\x83W</span></td>\n\t</tr>\n\t</table>\n\t<!-- page title end. -->\n\n\t<!-- page body begin. -->\n\t<hr>\n\t<br>\n\t<br>\n\t\x81@\x81@\x81@\x81@\x96{\x83y\x81[\x83W\x82\xcd\x88\xf8\x82\xc1\x89z\x82\xb5\x92v\x82\xb5\x82\xdc\x82\xb5\x82\xbd\x81B<br>\n\t<br>\n\t\x81@\x81@\x81@\x81@\x90V\x82\xb5\x82\xa2\x82t\x82q\x82k\x82\xcd<a href="https://www.e-shiten.jp/e_api/">\x82\xb1\x82\xbf\x82\xe7</a>\x82\xc5\x82\xb7\x81B<br>\n</body>\n<script>\n$(function ()\n{\n\t$(\'.page_logo\').attr (\'src\', \'logo_web.gif\');\n\t$(\'body\').css (\'display\', \'\');\n});\n</script>\n</html>\n'
```

Comment: 上記コマンドより、urllib3を2.xxから1.xx系の最終版に戻したところ、エラーが解消されました。GoogleColabからも、期待する結果を得ることができるようになりました。ありがとうございました。